# Website different on PC and on Mobile with DESKTOP VIEW ENABLED React

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

new to React, when i start website from cmd and I access it from PC it's normal like usually, when I open it on a phone **WITH DESKTOP SITE ENABLED** it's different, I tested it and it's like if I move element for ex. 20px at **mobile desktop view** it'll move for 70px.

How can I have it fixed, so when I move something for ex. **100px** to have it move exactly **100px** both on Desktop and Mobile with Desktop View.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKt15.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfdZ1.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

you should try something with css

```
@media(max-width: [screen size in px]) {
        .div{
            width: ...;
        }
    }
```